# Ruby and Ruby on Rails offline API documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, documentation

In the past I used railsbrain.com to have a nice and handy offline api documentation.

But they stop at version 2.3.2

Is there any other solution with latest version.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Browser-based Solution** – *Updated Oct 19, 2017*

[DevDocs](https://devdocs.io/offline) (https://devdocs.io/) uses your browser's IndexedDB to store the documentation you want. Make sure you follow the instructions on how to install the docs before you go offline.

---

For **macOS** try [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash)

For **Windows/Linux** try [Zeal](https://github.com/zealdocs/zeal)

For **packaged HTML** try [RubyDocs](https://rubydocs.org/)

**Manual Download**:

I used this commands on my server so I could get the files faster (they were cached, go figure).

`wget -r -k -p http://api.rubyonrails.org/`

- r - recursive
- k - convert links to point to local files
- p - get all
  images, etc needed to display the html pages

Then I compress the folder so I can download it without overhead.

`rar a -r rails_api.rar api.rubyonrails.org/`

- a - add files
- r - recursive

https://gist.github.com/2149669

**YARD Server**

I prefer the yard format over rdoc.

1. Install the gem `gem install yard`,
2. Regenerate all the documentation `gem rdoc --all --overwrite`, and
3. Run the server for the gems `yard server --gems`.

Comment: +1 for Dash reference. Never heard of it before. I think I'm gonna like it!!

Comment: thanks for sharing a link to Dash. liking it so far!

Comment: For later versions of Rubygems: `gem rdoc --rdoc --all`

Answer (score 24):

[railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com). You can build and download a custom package of docs for ruby versions to 1.9, rails to 2.3.5 and a number of gems.

Comment: `not found` when you try download :( Dammit.

Answer (score 16):

I realize this question is quite old but since it still comes up high in Google when searching for "ruby on rails docs" and several people suggest railsapi.com, which has been down for almost a year.

So I wanted to mention http://rubydocs.org, which has the same functionalities that railsapi.com had and more (generate combined docs of Ruby and Rails with any version you need).

Disclaimer: I built http://rubydocs.org. :)

Comment: Why do I have to wait for the docs to be prepared? Can't you just create all possible combinations and have them stored on the server?

Comment: RubyDocs currently tracks 281 Ruby versions and 213 Rails versions. All possible combinations would be close to 60,000. While it's totally possible to generate and store all those, it would be a waste of time and space since only a few are really useful I guess.

Comment: Nice and very helpful. But, I I need yardoc instead, what should I do?

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 9):

Within your rails project:

**API:**

```
rake doc:rails
```

**Guides:**

Add the RedCloth gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'RedCloth'
```

Then

```
rake doc:guides
```

Comment: Good answer. But, if I want to use yardoc instead of rdoc for api documentation, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 5):

Edit (Feb 2016): http://devdocs.io/ looks okay

Just not to pass unmentioned, you can also start local gem rdoc server:

```
$ gem server
Starting gem server on http://localhost:8808/
localhost - - [13/Mar/2010:18:34:44 CET] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 22403
- -> /
```

But it lacks info on core Ruby library.

Comment: +1 for gem server. Re: missing core library info, I think that the [rdoc-data](http://blog.segment7.net/2010/04/01/rdoc-data-2-5-1) gem will help there.

Comment: DevDocs! Wow! Where have you been all my life?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend `bdoc`. It is a replacement for `gem server` that does not require to have a server running and looks much nicer. Just do `gem install bdoc; bdoc` or check out more details here. You can find bdoc [here](https://github.com/rmanalan/bdoc).

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Mac, i've put together a dictionary with Rails 3.0 documentation http://prii.it/blog/rails-3-dictionary-update. I haven't had time to do it for Rails 3 but will do that once i'm in the mood.

Other Rails versions are available too.

Answer (score 3):

I found [Aslam's post on this topic](http://aslamnajeebdeen.com/blog/how-to-create-your-own-local-copy-of-rails-api-doc-and-guides) to be the most useful, easy to implement answer to this question, and it works for current version of the Rails API and Rails Guides. Thanks to Aslam for putting it together.

Basically, you clone the current Rails git repo to your computer and then run

```
bundle exec rake rdoc
```

from within the rails directory.

From there, you can copy the documentation folder to somewhere else on your computer and run locally from a browser.

Aslam's post also shows you how to generate a copy of the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 2):

What about http://railsapi.com/?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows [Build your own Ruby and Rails Searchable API Doc](http://pjkh.com/articles/building-your-own-rails-and-ruby-searchable-api-docs/) post is a good way to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apidoco` gem. Its easy and simple to use. Got so many flexible features too.

Gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/apidoco/versions/0.1.0

Docs: https://github.com/72pulses/apidoco

Comment: I have used this gem on my project. It's good and very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I used to use FXRI, which was quite cool: http://rubyforge.org/projects/fxri/

Though, I have no idea if it still works or if it plays nice with rvm. I guess it has been abandoned.
It is a pity though, it was a very nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question in a Google search while looking for offline documentation. It did the job but I'm posting this link that currently contains (and makes it easier) all the docs for offline usage for other people who find themselves here. [DOCS](https://rubydocs.org/?__s=xsgnk7ugkjzhbinjbqxg)